# Can chrome extensions or javascript use the native functionality of an operating system?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Can chrome or any web browser extensions or javascript reach out to the native functionality of an operating system such as windows hello api?

Comment: An extension can use it via an additional connector app. See the documentation for nativeMessaging API.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no, unless the browser specifically wants to expose that interop.

Chrome and other browsers support Windows Hello (in latest versions) via the WebAuthn APIs.

For instance, in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 RS4+ or on Windows 10 Insider builds with Chrome 72+, you can use Windows Hello as a "Platform Authenticator" via https://webauthntest.azurewebsites.net/.

Other APIs are exposed on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped a lot. I did not know that something like this exists. But It is fairly new as far I see. So we will be able to use those protocols in wide range in the near future.